# Symfony - Redirect to action with form values filled in

Tags: symfony1, symfony-1.4, symfony-forms

How can I do a redirect to another action, and get the form fields to be filled in on the new action?

I have an action and I want to call redirect() something like:

```
$this->redirect('foo/search?Search[last_name]='.$this->form->getValue('last_name'));
```

Which should redirect to my Search action, and the form in that action should get the last_name parameter filled in. That action has code like so:

```
public function executeSearch(sfWebRequest $request)
{
   $this->form = new SearchForm();
   $submission = $request->getParameter($this->form->getName());
   ...do stuff with $submission...
```

The SearchForm has the name format 'Search[%s]'.

Nothing I've tried for the parameter to redirect() has worked. The Search[] parameters always get messed up in some way and will not populate the form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would try to get Symfony to generate the URL for you based on the route and parameters:

```
@search = a route for your search action in your routing.yml

$parameters = array of the parameters you want to pass

$url = $this->generateUrl('search', $parameters);
$this->redirect($url);
```

The array of parameters should take the following format...

```
'Search[something1]' => 'value1'
'Search[something2]' => 'value2'
```

... so the URL takes them as:

```
?Search[something1]=value1&Search[something2]=value2
```

You should then be able to use...

```
$this->form->bind($request->getParameter('Search'));
(for binding)
```

... and probably even...

```
$this->form->setDefaults($request->getParameter('Search'));
(for populating for a template)
```

Hope that helps or at least gives you some ideas.

Comment: Yes! Thank you. I had not seen that generateUrl() method before. Creating URLs with the routing in Symfony gives me more fits than anything else in the framework.

Answer (score 0):

Try [this solution](http://oldforum.symfony-project.org/index.php/m/33219/).

Another method is to store submission data in user session.